# Audio Recording html5 on iOS

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio

I am attemping to access the microphone on iOS in order to capture user input.

```
<input type="file" accept="audio/*;capture=microphone">
```

But whenever I click this I see the options (take photo or video, photo library)

How can I access the microphone only?

Comment: That's an old syntax, you should use `<input type="file" name="video" accept="audio/*" capture>` . See [Correct Syntax for HTML Media Capture](https://addpipe.com/blog/correct-syntax-html-media-capture/).

Answer (score 2):

As of IOS 8.3, it's not supported by Safari.

http://caniuse.com/#search=getusermedia

Comment: Still not supported in iOS 11.1 .

Comment: while getUserMedia is supported, MediaRecorderAPI is not: https://caniuse.com/#search=mediarecorder
That means that you can get a raw buffer from the getUserMedia, but it's up to you to process it and convert into a playable file. 
I think that whatsapp web (which supports voice recording on iOS 11) does exactly that with asm.js OPUS codec implementation.