# Voice recording on iPhone by using Safari and HTML5

Tags: javascript, ios, html, voice-recording

I am developing a simple web application which only records a voice from microphone but I have some trouble.

HTML5 voice recording function works well on chrome and firefox desktop or android. But while using mobile browsers on iPhone even chrome and firefox it doesn't work.

I tried recorder.js and result did not change.

Is it possible to recording voice on safari or it is a missing function of safari or iOS?

Comment: Try this approach https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/native-hardware/recording-audio/

Comment: @StephenTetreault: That would have been better off as an answer (so long as it spelt out what was explained on that page rather than being just the link).

Comment: @StephenTetreault: This does not work for me (tested with iOS 12, Android 9) - accept audio/* with capture attribute set only brings up the camera app which cannot record audio.

Answer (score 18):

May 2018 Update (because figuring this out has been tough with all the outdated info).

I found this demo that proves it is possible: https://kaliatech.github.io/web-audio-recording-tests/dist/#/test1

Comment: Keep in mind apple only added proper webrtc support in mobile safari. its still totally F'ed in chrome/ff/webviews. half-assed job by apple.

Comment: This github repo is awesome! Works far better than any packaged solutions. And he's calling it just "tests" wow

Comment: I think Apple became the new internet explorer. Now that finally that Microsoft got awesome and went with Edge...

Comment: My only issue with this is, that the recording formats differ between Safari and other browsers (mp4 vs webm). The demo confirmed my problem (see the recorded file name). This is why I don't think a browser-only solution (with firebase) is enough to be able to have Safari play the recordings of other users and it might be time to integrate ffmpeg (or something else) in some backend (maybe the firebase cloud functions)

Answer (score 12):

As far as I knew, even on the latest iOS (iOS 10), recording voice on iOS using HTML5 is still impossible. Since all the browsers on iOS are limited to use UIWebView which Safari on iOS uses as well, Chrome on iOS is not able to support any API that can be used for media recording.
For example, recorder.js which you used are built on Media Capture API. If you check [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=Media%20Capture), you will find this API is not supported on iOS. (Also check the issue [here](https://github.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs/issues/160)).
[MediaRecorder API](https://w3c.github.io/mediacapture-record/MediaRecorder.html) is also a promising API but still [not supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=mediarecorder) by Apple's browser.

Check answers below for more information.
1. [Record voice from IPhone using HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25287112/record-voice-from-iphone-using-html5)
2. [Audio Recording html5 on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31248773/audio-recording-html5-on-ios)

Comment: Safari is the new IE.

Comment: I can't believe its still not supported

Comment: any update about if this is  been planning to support? it's such a mess that even using chrome on IOS still impossible to use MediaRecorder API

Comment: @StephenTetreault just ...lol.. and apple is still the new... apple

Answer (score 10):

Since iOS11, Safari now supports Media Capture API:

> New in Safari 11.0 – Camera and microphone access.
>
> Added support for the Media Capture API.
> Added ability for websites to access camera and microphone streams from a user's
> device (user permission is required.)

[Announcement by Apple - broken link as of Jul 2018](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewInSafari/Safari_11_0/Safari_11_0.html)

[A copy of the announcement on someone's blog](https://thenewdialtone.com/hold-apple-webrtc-ios-party/)

Therefore recorder.js will work now.

Comment: I try record audio in iOS11 but recorder.js dont work.

Comment: K48, Were you successful with recorder.js on IOS11?

Comment: @visual unfortunately not

Comment: audio recording and playback does work in IOS/Safari 11 BUT only from the browser. Standalone (aka save to home screen web app capable) apps do not work nor are they even recognized by the web inspector (which is apparently a bug)

Comment: We could not get the microphone to work. Recorder is `undefined` on iPad Safari and Chrome. Check the code and try it yourself: https://github.com/q2apro/js-snippet-audiorecord-getUserMedia/blob/master/audiorecord.js

Comment: The link seems to be broken now

Comment: @KerryDavis I don't believe it to be a bug. I went deep into this issue when i found webrtc not workign in chrome, ff, social app webviews. I recall stumbling upon a forum posts where one of the apple support team members just said it wasn't implemented and they didn't have a roadmap for it. This was months ago though and I can't seem to track down the link. Half-assed from Apple if you ask me.

Answer (score 10):

It's now possible and "easy" to do on iOS11 for Safari!  The mediaStream API is supported now.  The mediaRecorder API however is not.  This causes any existing examples out there to not work.  So you'll have to implement your own mediaRecorder functionality by connecting the media stream to a webkitAudioContext ScriptProcessorNode and collect the stream buffer on the node's onaudioprocess event.  You can then collect the iOS microphone's streaming audio data and do with it what you want, most likely merging it into a wav file for upload/download.  This works for any browser that supports the Media Stream API.

Two gotcha's:
 - iOS Safari likes to deallocate any AudioContext that wasn't created on the main thread (on a tap) so you can't initialize it on the device media access accepted callback.
 - The scriptProccessorNode wont fire any audioprocessed events unless the input AND output are connected for some reason.

Comment: Would you be able to post &| link to any code demonstrating this?  I am still struggling to get non-zero-length audio data.

Comment: Don't forget one more gotcha: AudioContext can only be created upon user interaction (i.e., touchend, click, etc.)

Comment: Thanks for the tip about connecting both the input and the output, was driving me crazy!

Answer (score 1):

Safari on iOS 11 does NOT support the 2 standards which would make audio (only) recording possible (and easy to implement):

- **HTML Media Capture** for audio ([spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-media-capture/), [correct syntax](https://blog.addpipe.com/correct-syntax-html-media-capture/) ) -  audio recording should be passed to a native app which should pass the result back to the browser for upload (it works for video and picture)
- **MediaStream Recording API** ([spec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStream_Recording_API), [demo](https://addpipe.com/media-recorder-api-demo/)) - allows you to record to a blob directly in the browser. The recording can be downloaded or uploaded to a web server.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the new iPhone 11 ProMax, with iOS13.3, and have been trying to build out a web app with voice recognition services via HTML5 to work in safari or any browser on my iPhone. It seems iOS developers have blocked audio / video recording at the os level. There is a limited workaround however that might be useful for someone coming here as I did.
https://blog.addpipe.com/safari-technology-preview-73-adds-limited-mediastream-recorder-api-support/

Basically, if you go into advanced settings for safari you can enable the mediaRecorder. Their demo works with video capture, I have not seen it with pure audio yet.