# HTML5 form audio input from iOS device directly

Tags: ios, html, forms, audio, input

I want to build a HTML5 form, in which user can submit audio file from the desktop, and for mobile device, user have to record the audio directly. I use the following html5 code for the audio input

`<input type="file" accept="audio/*" id="capture" capture="microphone">`

It works properly, but not iOS device, and which always give me .mov video files instead of any audio.

Is it the limitation of iOS? And is there any workaround for my case?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's just not supported through iOS and it's been that way for a few versions.  Check out [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42221646/voice-recording-on-iphone-by-using-safari-and-html5?noredirect=1&lq=1) from another post.